# How to determine if a C++ object is a time_t

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, rtti, template-specialization

How can I determine if a C++ object is a time_t, as opposed to the integral type time_t is defined as?

I specifically want to template specialize a function,

```
template <typename T> void myFunction( T val );
template<>            void myFunction<time_t>( time_t val );
```

such that the unspecialized function gets called when the integral type which time_t is defined as gets passed.

My STL implementation defines `time_t` as `long`, so `myFunction(42L)` calls the time_t specialization. How can I prevent this?

I tried specializing `long`, which results in a compile error (body has already been defined). I also tried the rtti, `typeid(time_t).name()` returns `"long"`.

How can I discriminate between `time_t` and the integral type it is defined as, and/or template specialize time_t such that its integral type does not get passed to the specialization?

A way to do it with templates would be preferable, but I would accept any solution, run-time or compile-time.

Comment: You might be interested in [an implementation of strong typedefs provided by Dr. Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/184401633)

Comment: Ben, I wish that had been an answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to prevent this.

In C++, a `typedef` is equivalent to its base type for **all** purposes. At compile time, they are equivalent. At run time, they are equivalent.

You could remove the definition of `time_t` entirely and redefine it as a different type, but that would break the user code's ability to call a function expecting a proper `time_t`.

Answer (score 3):

You fundamentally can't get what you want.  `time_t` is defined (at least in the C standard) as a `typedef` (the hint is the "`_t`" part of the name), which does not introduce a new type.  You want to make a distinction between whether somebody calls the one name or another, but C and C++ don't allow that.